# How to show an alertView showing the server side delay

Tags: iphone, ios5, uialertview, delay

There is a delay from the server side, about 10 seconds. I want to display an alertView showing that delay in server. How to do it?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried)

Answer (score 2):

If the delay is fixed of 10 seconds. Then you can put a custom AlertView Showing an indicator to wait for 10 seconds and dismiss the AlertView after 10 seconds. You can use NSTimer to manage the time interval of 10 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

You can also show an activity indicator showing that the request is currently in progress and remove the activity indicator if the request is done.